# Box plot of deciles that are not unique

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot with 10 box plots together, each representing a decile of the data set. However, some of the deciles are identical and ggplot will not plot the graph unless they are. Answers I have seen for similar questions suggest removing the non-unique deciles or adding data to make them unique. In my case, however, it is important to show that some are not unique.

This is my code (without formatting):

```
mydata$metric_deciles <- with(mydata, cut(metric, breaks=quantile(metric, probs=seq(0,1, by=0.1), na.rm=TRUE), include.lowest=TRUE, dig.lab = 10))
p1 <- ggplot(na.omit(mydata), aes(factor(metric), metric2))
p1 <- p1 + geom_boxplot()
p1 <- p1 + scale_x_discrete(NULL, labels = c("10%", "20%", "30%", "40%", "50%", "60%", "70%", "80%", "90%", "100%"))
```

Which, on a data set where deciles are unique, looks like this:

[image]

On the first line, I get `error in cut.default: 'breaks' are not unique`.

I am looking for a way to plot all 10 deciles even if some are not unique (i.e. some of the box plots will be the same).

Comment: FYI, to create the labels, you can just do `paste0(seq(10,100,10), "%")`

Comment: This isn't a `ggplot2` issue. The error is occurring with the `cut` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring because there is at least one value of `metric` that's repeated and straddles one of the quantile break points. This is what is causing the error in `cut`. You can instead create the deciles by ranking by the variable for which you want to create deciles. Here's an example with the built-in `iris` data frame:

```
# Create decile labels based on Petal.Width.
# First, rank by Petal.Width, then divide by the number of values we want in each decile.
#  Then, multiply by 10 and paste on "%" to get the label names.
iris$decile = paste0((rank(iris$Petal.Width, ties.method="random") %/% (nrow(iris)/9.99) + 1)*10, "%")

# Put the labels in the correct order
iris$decile = factor(iris$decile, levels=paste0(seq(10,100,10),"%"))
```

Note in the code above that some rows with the same Petal.Width end up in different deciles, which is what causes the problem of duplicate levels when using `cut` with levels chosen by `quantile`. The code above uses `rank` and breaks ties randomly.

```
# Plot boxplots of Sepal.Width by decile of Petal.Width
ggplot(iris, aes(decile, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I think it is most of the way there. However, because some of the deciles are identical (the 7th-10th deciles are all 100% data$metric values), I think it would be best to group all of the 100% data that in the 7th percentile and duplicate that box plot for the 8th-10th. At the moment, it is misleading because it has split the data$metric2 values so the box plots show a trend that does not exist.